# How to restrict access of Azure App Service to only users added in user and group setting in Azure Ad?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My angular .net core 2.0 app uses oauth2.0 authentication and i have configured the same in startup.cs. PFB Code

```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()

            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = azureAdConfig.ClientSecret;
                options.Authority = string.Format(azureAdConfig.AADInstance, azureAdConfig.Tenant);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.Resource = azureAdConfig.ResourceURI_Graph;
              options.Events = new AuthEvents(azureAdConfig, connectionStringsConfig);
            });
```

App works fine, but now i want to **restrict** App to be used by set of users. For which i have added required users and groups in Azure AD app.
 
Then i have enabled following settings in azure app service.
[image]

Also i have enabled **User Assignment required** setting in Azure AD Enterprise Application. PFB
[image]

But now, when i access the application, i get following error: ( **i have added required reply urls**)

[image]

Comment: Is this Azure B2C?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using OpenID Connect to sign in users from AAD , using the ASP.Net OpenID Connect OWIN middleware in web application , you don't need to config the [built-in authentication and authorization support of App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) .

Try to disable the `authentication and authorization` feature , enable `user assignment required` of AAD app , and let OIDC middleware in your application to control the authentication process .

Comment: It worked thanks !!! But only issue is it shows login page to user and after user clicks on login it says unable to login

Comment: That will be something else block the login , checking the error message .